# в nextjs двигается RootLayout вместе с текстом

Tags: nextjs

у меня маленький сайт  в nextjs есть RootLayout и там у меня цвет заднего фона и вверху такая полоска div на каторой размещены кнопки для перемещения по страницам , я начал делать главную страницу разместил там тег h1 и когда загружаю страницу у меня h1 находится выше чем layout ,а мне надо чтобы он был ниже ,если я пишу margin-top то у меня вместо текста двигается полоска layout еще ниже

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: мне нужно чтобы мой текст на страничке был по центру я пытаюсь его двигать ниже с помощью margin-top ,но у меня вместе с ним двигается layout